# Unable to find object when trying to attach mailitem

Tags: c#, vsto, mailitem

I'm writing a little app on c# to VisualStudio 2017 for Office 2010

```
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MailItem SelectedMessage = (Outlook.MailItem)app.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
Outlook.MailItem newmail = app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Outlook.MailItem;

newmail.Subject = SelectedMessage.SenderEmailAddress + " - " + SelectedMessage.Subject;
newmail.To = SenderEmailVar;

newmail.Body += "Subject : " + SelectedMessage.Subject;
newmail.Body += "Received by : " + SelectedMessage.SendUsingAccount.SmtpAddress;
newmail.Body += "Sent by : " + SelectedMessage.SenderEmailAddress + "\n\n";

MessageBox.Show(SelectedMessage.Body);
newmail.Attachments.Add(SelectedMessage);
newmail.Send();
```

But I have an exception:

> Unable to find object

Sorry it's in French (I tried to translate it).

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException occured.
>         HResult=0x8004010F
>         Message=Operation failed. Unable to find object.
>         Source=Microsoft Outlook
>         procedural call tree :
>   Unable to evaluate the procedure call tree of the exception

It occurs on the `newmail.Attachments.Add(SelectedMessage);` line.

I can have the `SelectedMessage.Subject`, `SelectedMessage.Body` fine, so my selection is not empty.

MessageBox working fine, and body&subject of the new message contain the subject, sender, etc... So the selection seems to be working. But the source email is not attached.

What's wrong ?

Regards

Comment: Hi, can you post the complete exception details and the line number where it occurs?

Comment: what is `SelectedMessage`?

Comment: @BarryO'Kane: I think it is `Outlook.MailItem SelectedMessage = (Outlook.MailItem)app.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];`

Comment: @Stefan yes it's true, SelectedMessage is my selection from ActiveExplorer().

Comment: @Stefan done ;)

Comment: I cannot find any info on: `Attachments.Add`, have you got a link to some documentation?

Comment: Sure : Attachments.Add Method (Outlook) : https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ff869553.aspx

Comment: Or are there any another way to do this ?

Comment: I don't know, you should try to google that. An other thought: have you tried to specify the `type` in the `Attachments.Add` method?

Comment: I think its not a type problem, because i can read for other properties (like subject or body)

Answer (score 0):

**Find a workaround :**

First, i save the message locally to the disk

Then, attach this MSG file to the current email.

And delete the mail from the disk.

```
SelectedMessage.SaveAs(Path.GetTempPath() + "cmail.msg");
newmail.Attachments.Add(Path.GetTempPath() + "cmail.msg");
File.Delete(Path.GetTempPath() + "cmail.msg");
```

Probably not the best, but working fine.
If someone can be better, i'm looking for :)